# android:theme - specify in <application> or in <activity>?

Tags: android, android-theme

If there is just one `Activity` in an Android App, is it better to specify the `android:theme` attribute in `<application>` or in `<activity>` tag of `AndroidManifest`?

Does app launch faster if `android:theme` is in `<application>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

if you use theme on application tag, It's automatically will apply for all activities.

If you have to apply different themes for different activities , you can set theme on activity tag.

so there no different on performance.

Finally `android:theme` on application is universal and `android:theme` on activity is specific or individual.